# Не могу установить расширение .vsix Visual Micro Arduino MS VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, arduino

Скачал расширение Visual.Micro.Arduino.Studio.vsix , но Windows игнорирует все мои попытки установить его. Два клика по файлу игнорирует. Перенес в папку <Папка установки Visual Studio>\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ – ноль эмоций. Пытался указать адрес ссылки на скачивание, как личную галерею расширений– ноль. Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

- Установите C++ как язык программирования. Control Panel/Add Or Remove Programs/Visual Studio 2015/Change. Затем выберите C++ в списке доступных опций.
- Откройте Extension Manager (Tools/Options). Затем выберите Visual Micro.